# C# Can I call either of the two: class.method.method? Or class.class.method?

Tags: c#

C# beginner here.. So my example is next:

I have a 'Car' class with two methods: 'Wheels' , 'Doors'. I also need that my two methods call other methods like 'Color' or 'Shape' so in the end I will be able to call:

```
Car car = new Car();

car.Wheels.Shape();

car.Doors.Color();
```

Would that be possible somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, if the type of `car.Wheels` has a `Shape`-method. Show the type of `Wheels`.

Comment: In your example `Wheels` and `Doors` are not methods, I suppose they are properties. Do you want to achieve method chaining or something else?

Comment: You probably need to read a bit while you take your first steps. If you don't have access to a C# introduction, look online. For example, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470(v=vs.71).aspx would probably be helpful. Or https://www.dotnetperls.com/property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should introduce classes for Shape, Color, Doors, Wheels and Car. Then you should add Color-typed property for Doors class and Shape-typed property for Wheels class.

```
  public class Color { }
  public class Shape { }

  public class Wheels
  {
    public Shape Shape { get; set; }
  }

  public class Doors
  {
    public Color Color { get; set; }
  }

  public class Car
  {
    public Doors Doors { get; set; }
    public Wheels Wheels { get; set; }

    public Car()
    {
      Doors = new Doors();
      Wheels = new Wheels();
    }

    public void PaintDoors(Color color)
    {
      Doors.Color = color;
    }

    public void ChangeWheelsShape(Shape shape)
    {
      Wheels.Shape = shape;
    }
  }
```